# Printing to console doesnt work when substituting variable within another variable in bash

Tags: bash

I am observing a weird issue where when I substitute a variable(A) within another variable(B) and print variable B , the console output is messed up.

```
docker_command="docker ps | grep consul | awk '{print \$1}'"
container_id=$(execute_command_on_host $IP $USER_NAME $USER_PASSWD "$docker_command")
echo "container_id: $container_id"
service_command="docker exec "$container_id" consul catalog services"
echo "service_command: $service_command"

#run script

Output:

container_id: 411d55019dba
consul catalog servicesommand: docker exec 411d55019dba
```

The last line of the output is messed up and sort of jumbled. But the same script if I run directy using the container_id then it works

```
container_id="411d55019dba"
service_command="docker exec "$container_id" consul catalog services"
echo "service_command: $service_command"

#run script

Output:

service_command: docker exec 411d55019dba consul catalog services
```

I feel I am missing out on something very simple. Would appreciate any help

Comment: Use either backticks or `$()` to execute a command. Now you're asigning the strings to a variable.

Comment: Please don't pipe trivial grep to awk.  `... | grep "pattern" | awk "{print $1}"` is better written `... | awk "/pattern/{print $1}"`

Comment: @FredrikPihl I have used $() to obtain the container_id actually.
container_id=$(execute_command_on_host $IP $USER_NAME $USER_PASSWD "$docker_command")

With this the container_id should be a string right? Or should I be using $() elsewhere in my code too?

Updated my question

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following and it worked for me.

```
docker_command="docker ps | awk '/consul/{print \$1}' | tr -d '\r\n'"
```

Line encoding seemed to be the issue

Comment: All of this *screams* https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050